# If $ \sin ^{a}x+\cos ^{b}y=\sin ^{c}y+\cos ^{d}x\in \{ -1,1\}$ then $|\sin x+\cos x|=|\sin y+\cos y|=1$

Tags: trigonometry

If $x,y$ are real numbers,$a,b,c,d\geq 3$ are natural numbers such that   $\sin^{a} x+\cos^{b}{y}= \sin^{c}{y}+ \cos^{d}{x} \in \{ -1,1\}$ then $|\sin x + \cos x|=|\sin y+ \cos y|=1$

Comment: Please add some context.  Where does this come from?  Why do you think it's true?  How far have you gotten with it?

Comment: Why did you consider  $ x=\pm 1$? I think we can’t consider random values for x.

Comment: It is not x in {-1,1}. The expression $\sin ^{a}x+\cos^{b}y$ is in{-1,1}

Comment: I'm getting cross-eyed, I guess.  Sorry.